# Scheduling a build x times

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to understand the way to scheduling a job

- H 6 * * * -> this launch every day at morning

So How can I launch 3 builds every morning ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the "?" in the GUI to get this help:

```
To specify multiple values for one field, the following operators are available. In the order of precedence,

- * specifies all valid values
- M-N specifies a range of values
- M-N/X or */X steps by intervals of X through the specified range or whole valid range
- A,B,...,Z enumerates multiple values
```

With this help you should use

```
H 6-7/3 * * *
```

to get three build between 6 AM and 7 AM.